# Pass method as parameter

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a method in which you calculate the distance between two MyPoint objects. I don't know how to pass a MyPoint object as an argument in the first distance method. Thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

public class MyPoint {
 private double x1,y1;
 
    public MyPoint() {
        x1=0;
        y1=0;
        
    }
    public MyPoint(double x1, double y1) {
     this.x1 = x1;
     this.y1 = y1;
    }
    
    
    public double distance(myPoint) {
        
        
    }

    public double distance(double x2, double y2) {
        double distance = Math.sqrt(((x2-x1)*(x2-x1))+((y2-y1)*(y2-y1)));
        return distance;
    }
}
```

Comment: `distance(MyPoint point)`

Comment: This class seems to be incorrect logically.. 
If you already have the double x1, y1 as double inside the class, and you need to create a `new MyPoint` intance, why do you need to pass the argument while calling the distance methods - you can use this.x1 and this.x2

Comment: You can either do a static method and take 2 MyPoint instances as a parameter or distanceFrom instance method where you take 1 MyPoint instance being the other MyPoint instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do as the following code

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

public class MyPoint {
 private double x,y;
 
    public MyPoint() {
        x=0;
        y=0;
        
    }
    public MyPoint(double x, double y) {
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
    }
    
    public double distance(MyPoint other) {
        double distance = Math.sqrt(((this.x-other.x)*(the.x-other.x))+((this.y-other.y)*(this.y-other.y)));
        return distance;
    }

public static void main(String[] args){
    pointOne = new Point(2.2,3.3);
    pointTwo = new Point(3.3,2.2);
    System.out.println(pointOne.distance(pointTwo));
}
}
```

Comment: @killuabusher you can take a look with my main() function

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as below :

```
public class MyPoint {
 private double x1,y1;
 
  public MyPoint() {
      x1=0;
      y1=0;
        
  }

  public MyPoint(double x1, double y1) {
   this.x1 = x1;
   this.y1 = y1;
  }
    

  public double distance(final double x2, final double y2) {
    final double distance = Math.sqrt(((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1)) + ((y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1)));
    return distance;
  }

  public double distance(final MyPoint myPoint) {
    return distance(myPoint.x1, myPoint.y1);
  }

}
```

And you can call is as below:

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(final String[] args) {

    final MyPoint myPoint1 = new MyPoint(1, 1);
    final MyPoint myPoint2 = new MyPoint(2, 2);
    System.out.println(myPoint1.distance(myPoint));

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public double distance(MyPoint secondPoint) {
    //Here you calculate the distance between them.
}
```

In your main class:

```
MyPoint p1=new MyPoint(10,20);
MyPoint p2=new MyPoint(20,40);

System.out.println(p1.distance(p2));
```